# Drupal 7 book content can't display child content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-type

I'm using drupal 7, i need to create book to display process of work, first i had create a page type content, but when i try to click in parent to display childs detail can't work and childs become parents etc...

Page type in back-end:
[image]

Display in front-end:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What method are you using to set up tree-like structure? Maybe you can use standard menus for that?

Comment: i'm using drupal book i need to display each parent in div after when i cliked on parent can display child in the same div etc

Comment: try to change poids size, TEST1 (poids = 0) and children TEST CHILDREN (poids = -1). The children have a structure with poids.

Comment: Didn't work @DiegoCespedes, any other way using book-navigation.tpl.php